# Laravel 5 - One server / multiple databases determined by request

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables

So I am developing an application that has two kinds of deployments. One is they host everything and there is one application / one database and no issues. The second (the one this question will center around) will have one application but different database connections per client.

Access to each domain will be white-listed so we don't have to worry about one client popping another clients domain in and their is other authentication on top of that.

What I need is two-fold:

1. a way to determine the client that is accessing the application (request headers? domain driven?)
2. grab the configurations for said client so they only access their databases information (use a certain .env file based on client?).

One idea I have thought of is using apache to set env variables based on the domain requested. However, I would prefer to keep this handling inside of laravel. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer, but my advice would be to identify the client and then create yourself a database connection base on that client's config. Then add that connection to the IoC container for the rest of your application to use. In a way, that's almost the entire point of having the IoC container. (Though I admit that the 'manager' based workings of the database stuff might make this a little trickier - you need to find a way to change the 'default' DB connection that Laravel uses when you don't specify one, basically, but ideally with an already created object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do this very thing. As you noted, you need some authority that can map domains to clients, and then a away to fetch the client-specific settings.

Here is how we set it up:

1. We have different Apache vhost per client, with all the domains/aliases the client has setup. In the vhost file, Apache gives us one single env variable `CLIENT_ID`. That way we know who the client is, no matter which domain alias is being used at any one time.
2. We have a Laravel service provider then that looks at `env('CLIENT_ID')` and sets up a number of config options. One of the things that gets set is a client-specific path, where we store a number of client-specific resources and files. So we're doing something like this:

   `Config::set("paths.client", "/var/www/clients/" . env("CLIENT_ID"));`
3. Now that we have the client-specific paths setup, we can use `Dotenv` to go load a client-specific `.env` file for this client. Note we still have a root `.env` file in our app directory (Laravel expects it) which sets up common config. The client-specific `.env` file sets up client-specific stuff like SMTP settings, and of course database connection settings.

   `Dotenv::load(Config::get("paths.client"));`
4. Now that the client-specific `.env` is loaded, we can easily write to the `database.connections` config array. And from there on out, eloquent and everything else just work.

   `Config::set('database.connections.mysql', [
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
    ]);`

You wouldn't have to do it this way of course. We chose Apache vhosts as our authority for mapping domains to clients, but you could have a master database or just a config file. Then in your service provider, you just need to ask the master db (or the config file) what client needs to be setup.

From there your client settings could even be in the master database or config file, if you didn't want to store separate `.env` files. Whole lot of ways you can skin this cat.

Ultimately, however you get there, you once you set the database config connection array, you're good to go.

**Update**:

For anyone reading this in the future, there is another very simple way to load alternate `.env` files as mentioned in the comments below:

> If you set APP_ENV somehow before you get to Laravel (SetEnv in virtualhost etc) it will by default look for .env.*APP_ENV* (Ex: .env.demo) file. I am using SetEnv to set APP_ENV and then creating .env files for each client.

For our purposes, we didn't want client-specific `.env` files sitting in the root of our app. But it could work quite well for other situations.

Comment: perfect, this is exactly what i was looking for

Comment: Just an fyi, even though they don't document it, if you set APP_ENV somehow before you get to laravel (SetEnv in virtualhost etc) it will by default look for .env.<APP_ENV> file. I am using SetEnv to set APP_ENV and then creating .env files for each client.

Comment: your way allows you to set all sorts of configs and do so much more....but my situation only really needed the default implementation so im not going to over-complicate. Any chance you could add this default implementation into your answer?

Comment: @BillGarrison sure thing, added it to the answer for anyone down the road that stumbles onto this